# How to ignore WP_ERROR caused by "get_the_excerpt" method in an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, get-the-title, wp-error

```
function get_post_data(){
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    ...
    $data['title'] = get_the_title( $post_id );
    ...
    $data['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt( $post_id );        
    ...            
    echo json_encode( $data );

    wp_die();
```

}

The above code shows the scheme of the ajax call. Some data should be retriven from a post given by its ID outside the LOOP. This seems to work when the content fields like title and excerpt not empty. But when empty I get an Internal Server Error (500: admin-ajax.php not found). When I debug the PHP code it seems an WP_ERROR to be thrown after calling "get_the_excerpt".

I just wanted to get some kind of solution like:

```
If (get_the_excerpt( $post_id ) returns an WP_ERROR) then let $data['excerpt'] = '';
```

Anything I tried f.e. try{} catch{} won't work, also not when I insert this to initialize the loop:

```
setup_postdata($post_id);
```

in the second line of the "get_post_data" function.

(EDIT) RESOLVED:

The problem was caused by a conflict with the DIVI theme I used.
When I followed the error in the WP_ERROR class I got:

"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function et_builder_init_global_settings() in [websitefolderpath]\wp-content\themes\Divi\includes\builder\feature\gutenberg\blocks\Layout.php:228

And this is getting relevant in the get_the_excerpt method in the following line:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt, $post );
```

After updating DIVI to the last version the error no longer exists.

Maybe I won't use get_the_excerpt() method in future in this project because it maybe can have many side effects causing strange results or errors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not possible for `get_the_excerpt()` to return a `WP_Error`. You've skipped some code, and the error message should tell you which line is throwing the error. What's on that line?

Comment: I will now use get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post_id ) instead of get_the_excerpt same for the post_title use get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) - I think, it is better when getting post data outside the loop.

Comment: There’s nothing inherently vulnerable about `get_the_excerpt()`. There’s no reason a broken theme or plugin couldn’t also break `get_post_field()`. It’s not possible to write code that will not break if another plugin has introduced an error.

Comment: @JacobPeattie: get_the_excerpt uses filtering `apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt'` and so other plugins using this filter can more likely cause problems then `get_post_field()` that has no filtering. And using `get_the_excerpt()` outside the loop has some side effects, if there is no custom excerpt, because then `get_the_content()` will be called ...
So for me `get_post_field()` it is the better choise here.

Comment: `get_post_field()` doesn't have a filter directly in it, but it does use other functions that have plenty of hooks in them. If you have other reasons to use it, that's fine, but don't think it makes you immune from broken themes and plugins.